# Display text and images in same line in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to display a sequence of text/image/text in the same line in my HTML document and after hours I still haven't deciphered the problem. As of right now my html page looks like:[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFqxX.png)

I wanted the page to have text/image/text on the same line though as I stated. I tried making the div they are in float: left; and also display: inline; . Furthermore, I also tried display: inline-block; but that still didn't work.
Here is the css code I am working with: [css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ4xl.png)

If anyone could give me some insight that would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To increase your chances of gettting useful answers (and get your questions not downvoted), please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a start and then http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to set `display:inline-block;` to each element you want to appear inline (`h2`,`div`, and any others).

Lastly, you want to set the percentage `width` of each element such that the total is 99% or less (TBH I can't tell you why this is, it's just been my experience).

Comment: ya i got it, i wasn't setting the image to inline-block also, thanks man

Comment: @GrantAlex Please accept this answer as the correct answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer) if it solved your problem for you. : )